# Grouping by nested array keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this which groups all docs per person id. This works fine and it's based on the answer from @MajedBadawi in this other stackoverflow question: [Group by nested array key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74518738/group-by-nested-array-key)

```js
  const data = [
    {
      id: 222222,
      document_file_name: "4020653_FileName.pdf",
      document_updated_at: "2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z",
      document_type_label: "doc label",
      state: "accepted",
      details: [
        {
          id: 20656,
          type: "Claimant",
          name: "First Name Last Name",
          first_name: "First Name",
          last_name: "Last Name",
          type_label: "claimant"
        },
        {
          id: 20657,
          type: "Fellow",
          name: "Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name",
          first_name: "Fellow First Name",
          last_name: "Fellow Last Name",
          type_label: "fellow"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 1111111,
      document_file_name: "4020600_FileName.pdf",
      document_updated_at: "2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z",
      document_type_label: "doc label",
      state: "rejected",
      details: [
        {
          id: 20656,
          type: "Claimant",
          name: "First Name Last Name",
          first_name: "First Name",
          last_name: "Last Name",
          type_label: "claimant"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 333333,
      document_file_name: "4020890_FileName.pdf",
      document_updated_at: "2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z",
      document_type_label: "doc label",
      state: "rejected",
      details: [
        {
          id: 20657,
          type: "Fellow",
          name: "Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name",
          first_name: "Fellow First Name",
          last_name: "Fellow Last Name",
          type_label: "fellow"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 444444,
      document_file_name: "4020672_FileName.pdf",
      document_updated_at: "2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z",
      document_type_label: "doc label",
      state: "rejected",
      details: [
        {
          id: 20656,
          type: "Claimant",
          name: "First Name Last Name",
          first_name: "First Name",
          last_name: "Last Name",
          type_label: "claimant"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  let name = [
    {
      id: "89",
      state: "accepted",
      document_type_label: "doc label",
      details: [
        {
          id: 20656,
          type: "Claimant",
          name: "First Name Last Name",
          first_name: "First Name",
          last_name: "Last Name",
          type_label: "claimant"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "45",
      state: "accepted",
      document_type_label: "doc label",
      details: [
        {
          id: 20656,
          type: "Claimant",
          name: "First Name Last Name",
          first_name: "First Name",
          last_name: "Last Name",
          type_label: "claimant"
        },
        {
          id: 20657,
          type: "Fellow",
          name: "Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name",
          first_name: "Fellow First Name",
          last_name: "Fellow Last Name",
          type_label: "fellow"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "47",
      state: "rejected",
      document_type_label: "doc label",
      details: [
        {
          id: 20657,
          type: "Fellow",
          name: "Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name",
          first_name: "Fellow First Name",
          last_name: "Fellow Last Name",
          type_label: "fellow"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  const groups = [
    ...data
      .reduce(
        (detailMap, { id: docId, document_file_name, document_type_label, state, details = [] }) => {
          details.forEach(({ id, type, name }) => {
            const detail = detailMap.get(id) ?? { id, type, name, docs: [] };
            detail.docs.push({ docId, document_file_name, document_type_label, state });
            detailMap.set(id, detail);
          });
          return detailMap;
        },
        new Map()
      )
      .values()
  ];
  console.log("groups: ", groups);
```

The problem is that I shouldn't have "repeated" docs in individual person as when it comes, for example, to doc `id: "222222"`. If there is a doc that has more than one person associated to it, it should show something like:

```
   {
    "id": [{"id":20656},{"id":20657}]
    "name": [{"name":"First Name Last Name"},{"name": "Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name"}]
    "docs": [
      {
        "docId": 222222,
        "document_file_name": "4020653_FileName.pdf",
        "document_type_label": "doc label",
        "state": "accepted"
      }
     ]
   }
```

Comment: @NinaScholz would you care to elaborate?

Comment: sorry. what is `name` array doing?

Comment: @NinaScholz in the wanted end result, it should show all names (`data.details.name`) that relate to that doc (`data.id`). As of right now, it shows only one name because it repeats the same doc per person if they both relate to it